# How can I make variables from elements of a xml string?

Tags: java, xml

The socket in the code below is connected to a program that generates weather data in xml String form.
My question is, how can I extract certain elements I need from the xml String and put them into variables so I can put them in a database for example?

```
import java.net.*;


import java.io.*;

class MyServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4999);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected");
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String str = "", str2 = "";
        while (!str.equals("stop")) {
            str = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("client says: " + str);
            str2 = br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(str2);
            dout.flush();
        }
        din.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    }

   

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the XML? If yes, a simple *web search* will find you lots of ways to do that.

Comment: No, i already have a program that parses an xml file, however this takes a file as input. The data i recieve from this generator however does not send files, it send an input stream which i convert to string. Was hoping there was an easy way to convert this string back to a xml file so i can use my program instead of having to write a new one.

Comment: So you ask the XML parser to read from an `InputStream` instead of from a file (which is a `FileInputStream`). Since you haven't shown which XML parser you would use, or how you're currently using it to read from file, we can't tell you what to change, but perhaps if you read the **documentation** of the XML parser in question, the way to do it would become clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML parsing library like Jackson. In theory you could write a parser yourself, but unless you're dealing with a very small subset of XML and see this as a learning opportunity, it will never be as reliable.

Have a look at this [Jackson tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization).

Comment: Why would you use third-party a XML parsing library like Jackson when Java comes with 3 different built-in XML parsers already (DOM, SAX, StAX)? Actually, 4 parsers for Java <= 8 (JAXB). --- For Java > 8, why would you recommend Jackson over JAXB?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not recommending any specific library, just giving an example of a library that is very easy to use.